# Moderator Election - Why do we reveal voting statistics while the poll is still open

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-election

With the moderator election I was worried that the first person (as you scroll down to view all candidates) would receive the most votes just due to people voting simply for the badges.

I was relieved to notice that the order of candidates shuffles every time you refresh the page to help evenly distribute the non-helpful votes that will shuffle in.

But then my second thought was, people probably also just go lazily vote for the person who already has the most up-votes.

When the polls first open, maybe one person with alot of friends gets all of said friends to go upvote them in the election, after those first few minutes they are ontop and it's almost like a snowball effect of people voting for the candidate that already has the most upvotes because they MUST be a good choice.

Why do we reveal voting stats while the elections are open?

Why not simply have a "Vote" button next to each candidate and it doesn't show how many other people have already voted for said candidate?

People who are voting just for the badges (which is probably enough to turn an election) probably just either vote for the first candidate they see or the one that has the most votes already. We already fixed the first issue by shuffling the order every-time, let's fix the second issue by hiding results until after the election!

Comment: Note that this only happens in the primary. In the actual election, you won't see how others voted.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thanks! I searched and couldn't find anything haha, must have used improper terms on google!